# Foreach variable not null after check still gives warning

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

See this sample:

```
var list = new List<string?>();

foreach (string item in list.Where(i => i != null))
{
    if (item.Length == 2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this sample, I get possible null reference in two places. The `foreach` variable and the dereferencing of `Length` in `if`. The second one I can easily fix by adding a dammit (null-forgiving) operator like this: `item!.Length`

Is there any way to do the same thing to the first one? I know that I can mark it as nullable string and check again but, I have already checked.

Comment: try this foreach (string? item in list.Where(i => i != null)) or better foreach (var item in list.Where(i => i != null))

Comment: Yes this will remove the immediate warning but I'll then have to check later for nullability of this string when I've already checked. I need some mechanism to tell the compiler that this `foreach` variable is not null.

Comment: Besides the correct answer below I do have a question: why would you create a list with nullable string, since it's already nullable?

Comment: @riffnl It's just a sample. My actual code is different. But in the new C# 10 and .Net 6 notation string (or any other reference type for that matter) is not nullable by default. Meaning that you can't assign null to it. It's still a warning, but soon it'll be an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply filtering using `Where`, you eliminate all null values, but this doesn't change the type of values.
All you need is to cast the results after filtering to the proper type:

```
foreach (string item in list.Where(i => i != null).Select(x => x!))
```

Comment: Good answer. I should have thought of this myself :))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `Where` predicate doesn't modify the caller's view of whether items in the enumerable are null or not.

The [approach given by Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436787/24874) involves additional runtime overhead due to the use of an extra `Select` call.

You can avoid that overhead via this extension method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source) where T : class
{
    foreach (T? item in source)
    {
        if (item != null)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```cs
foreach (string item in list.WhereNotNull())
{
    if (item.Length == 2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```